# SoundCloud API not working

Tags: ruby, api, soundcloud

I used to uploading my audio files to my SoundCloud Pro Unlimit subscription via API. It worked perfectly until last Saturday. Suddenly, it did not work since last Saturday. It always returns 500 Internal server error or 504 Gateway timeout. It would be great if SoundCloud can fix it as soon as practical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not the place to report a bug in SounCloud's systems.